# AngularJS: Show more or less is not working

Tags: angularjs

here is tiny code which is not working. i need to show and hide a para based on button click.

```
<div ng-init="more = false" ng-app="ang_app" ng-controller="CtrMain">
  <p ng-class="{'showMore': more, 'showLess': !more}">
    bla bla bla.
  </p>
  <button ng-click="more = !more">{{more ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}}</button>
</div>

var app=angular.module('ang_app', []);
    app.controller('CtrMain', function($scope) {
});

.showMore { height: auto; }
.showLess { max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden }
```

see my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/qg81dego/1/ and tell me what is missing there in code.

Comment: Your code is working, the p class changes when you click the button. If you want to hide an element you may want to check ng-show and ng-if directives.

Comment: you are missing the ng-if, ng-show in the <p> element

Comment: you haven't much content on `p` to show more/less, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/a8kvdxwb/

Comment: If you make 'bla bla bla' a much longer string, you can actually see that it works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/qg81dego/2/

Comment: You can less height to 10px in .showLess { max-height: 10px; overflow: hidden } to solve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show and hide a paragraph, then you have to set a property `display:none in showLess` class and `display:block in showMore` class Or You can set `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` accordingly.

You can also use ng-show, ng-hide and ng-if.

```
<p ng-show="more">Bla bla bla</p>
```

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

## Html

```
<div ng-init="more = false" ng-app="ang_app" ng-controller="CtrMain">
        <p ng-class="{'showMore': more, 'showLess': !more}">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.


        </p>
        <button ng-click="more = !more">{{more ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}}</button>
     </div>
```

## CSS:

```
.showLess { max-height: 15px;  overflow: hidden;}
.showMore { height:auto; }
```

It's working Now.